# Error al obtener la contraseña para autenticar un login

Tags: php, login

La cuestión está en que estoy oxidado en PHP. Al conectar la base de datos y querer probar un login me sale este error:

```
if( !$this->Solicitud->bind_param("ss", 
    $_POST["InpUsuario"], hash('sha256', 
    $_POST["InpContrasena"]))){
```

Error: Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference in /storage/ssd1/972/12167972/public_html/index.php on line 132

¿Alguien puede ayudarme con esto?

Answer (score 0):

Saca del método `bind_param`el hash que tratas de hacer y asignalo por fuera a una variable

```
$valorCambio = hash('sha256', $_POST["InpContrasena"]);
```

Y esta variable es la que pasarás como segundo argumento

```
if( !$this->Solicitud->bind_param("ss", $_POST["InpUsuario"], $valorCambio)){
```

Comment: Convendría explicar por qué hay que hacerlo así. `bind_param` sólo admite variables, no admite datos resultantes de llamadas a otra funciones.

Comment: perfecto ya lo resolvi, gracias

Comment: @RobertoMadrigalAlvarez recuerda que si la respuesta te fue de utilidad considera marcarla y/o votarla como aceptada. Saludos